# How to restrict file deletion via web application?

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc4 application. where I have custom code which upload the files in specific folder of my application. this code has option to delete files(uploaded on that) folder. 
I don’t have that code so I want to change permission of that folder so that it will not allow to delete files from that location via web application.windows its self send error for permission.
I have deny delete permission for the networksservices but not working.

now this is working for already images available in this folder. But now problem is when I am uploading new images it is allowing to delete a image means security permission hasn't applied to new images. why?
How/Which user should I assigned permission deny of delete?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user account under which your web site is running isn't networkservices.

If your application is hosted in IIS, you need to find the Application Pool for your web site and then check the user account used by this application pool. So check the properties of your web site on IIS, see the application pool name and then go to the Application Pools node in IIS console tree, find the application name and check its properties to find the related user.

Comment: I have deny delete for IIS app user it is xxxx\aaaadmin. but not working.

Comment: now this is working for already images available in this folder. But now problem is when I am uploading new images it is allowing to delete a image means security permission hasn't applied to new images. why?